# Execute a third party API call for every object in my queryset in a Django ListView

Tags: python, django

I have a `ListView` that displays every customer (class `Cliente` in my code) of a company.
Every `Cliente` object has a specific id (`piva` in my code) that is necessary to make a third party API call.
My goal was to press a button in the template that makes an API call for every `Cliente` object in my `ListView` queryset.

To accomplish this I overwrite the `get_context_data` method in the `ListView` to include a tuple of `piva`:

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    ctx = super().get_context_data()
    pive = pive_extraction(self.get_queryset())  # pive_extraction(qs: QuerySet[Cliente]) -> tuple[str]
    ctx['pive'] = pive
    return ctx
```

In my `ListView` template I have this form:

```
<form action="{% url 'crm:cerved-multiple-api-call' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input hidden name="ricerca" id="ricerca" value="{{pive}}">
    <button>Arricchimento Cerved di tutti i clienti</button>
</form>
```

Pressing the button perform the action on this view:

```
def cerved_multiple_api_call_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        pive = eval(request.POST['ricerca'])
        for piva in pive:
            data = cerved_api_call(piva) # third party API call
            # some non-relevant code where I work with 'data'

        return redirect('crm:cliente-list')
```

The code works fine and an API call is done for every `Cliente` in my `ListView` queryset;
But inserting a tuple of `piva` ids in the context, pass it as `request.POST` data, getting it `eval()` back into a `tuple[str]` (because it becomes a single `str` when passed in `request.POST`) and then performing an API call for every 'str' in my `tuple` smells like bad code. Any response is appreciated.